# Is there a way to make an object usable only by the first thread that accesses a specific method?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java-6

I want an object that can be created by any thread, but the moment a thread calls `myObject.use()` it can only be used by that thread until `myObject.release()` is called.

I don't want to force the developers to have to wrap all method calls for this object/class in synchronized blocks (which I know could be used to approximate this functionality) as that's likely to lead to misuse of the object if they forget to wrap all calls from `myObject.use()` to `myObject.release()` in the same synchronized block.

Is this possible?

Could it be done with a [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)?

Comment: Define _used by that thread_.

Comment: Sounds like an *object pool* to me.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Some instance in a thread calls the myObject instance's methods

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is probably a good idea. Can you say a bit more about why that's better than implementing this functionality in the class definiteion itself?

Comment: And what would you want to happen if another thread did? I think @ElliottFrisch is correct here.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ideally it would get an exception instead of blocking

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this. The pool is probably the best. You won't even be able to release an object unless it's available. Makes for cleaner code (handle exception at acquisition, not at use). Another option is to wrap your object in a proxy (think JDK proxies) and place the logic for atomically acquiring the instance before delegating to the real instance, then release the object. Then there's the full AOP solution which would be similar to the proxy.

Comment: Can I assume that "specific method" is a create method and the object itself stored in a ThreadLocal?

Answer (score 1):

Sure it can be done.  The `use()` method should be synchronized, so it can be called by only one thread at a time, and store the calling thread as the locking thread in a private volatile variable.  All calls - including `use()` - should first check if there is a stored locking thread and immediately return - or throw an exception if you prefer - if there is such a thread and it doesn't match the calling thread.  `release()` should also be synchronized and can remove the stored locking thread, allowing the next call to `use()` to store a new locking thread.

Comment: is there some way to do that to a class of a library we do not maintain? or only a fork? made me thing about how jRat works

Comment: @AquariusPower You could wrap the library class in a class of your own.